# How could I run two of my schedulers in parallel?

Tags: java, scheduler

I have been wanting for a long time to add schedulers to my API. So I set a class for the purpose. Here it is.

```
public abstract class SyncScheduler extends Scheduler {

private Thread thread = null;
private boolean repeating = false;

@Override
public synchronized void runTask() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public synchronized void runTaskLater(long delay) {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    thread.run();
}

@Override
public synchronized void runRepeatingTask(long period) {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    repeating = true;
    while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
        thread.run();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(period * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void cancel() {
    if (thread != null || !repeating) {
        throw new SchedulerException("Scheduler is not started or is not a repeating task!");
    } else {
        thread.interrupt();
        repeating = false;
    }
}}
```

Scheduler just implements Runnable.
The problem is that whenever I try to create 2 or more Schedulers, the second one never starts until the first one is finished! For example if I have on Scheduler that runs every X seconds and I have another one the cancels it, the one that cancels the first one never starts! This is the problem.

How could I run two of these schedulers in parallel?

Also these are my two test main classes.

```
public class Test {

static Scheduler scheduler = new SyncScheduler() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("It works.");

    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    scheduler.runRepeatingTask(1);
    new SyncScheduler() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Stopped.");
            scheduler.cancel();
        }
    }.runTaskLater(2);

}}
```

And here's the second one.

```
public class Test {

static Scheduler scheduler = new SyncScheduler() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("It works.");
        new SyncScheduler() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Stopped.");
                scheduler.cancel();
            }
        }.runTaskLater(2);
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    scheduler.runRepeatingTask(1);
}}
```

The first one outputs "It works." repeatedly until I force stop the test.
The second one gives me "It works." for once, then It gives me "Stopped." and with it and exception.

Comment: Need more information. Show us your main class and Scheduler as well.

Comment: If you want to run 2 "things" at the same time start use multiple threads

Comment: If you want to run two *threads* simultaneously, you might have to use count down latch http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html to stop both threads in one place and run together then.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the thread object wrongly.
To start a `Runnable` object (in this case, `Thread` object) in a different thread, the object must call `start()` method. You are using `run()` method, which just calling the method in the same thread without creating a new thread.

Try to change `run()` in `SyncScheduler.runRepeatingTask` and `SyncScheduler.runTaskLater`.

Also, I just noticed in your `cancel()` method:

```
if (thread != null || !repeating) {
    throw new SchedulerException("Scheduler is not started or is not a repeating task!");
} else {
    thread.interrupt();
    repeating = false;
}
```

This would make the method throw exception if thread started. I think it should be `if (thread == null || !repeating) {`

Comment: @Nick have you made sure your cancel method have the right condition?

Comment: Well I did not see that, thanks! But I don't think it's going to make a difference.